# Registration screen with 3 different user types

Tags: python, django

Well, I have the following registration screen and I have to basically have 3 types of users: Teacher, Licensing and Other.

Here is a link for the image because i don't have 10 points of reputation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqXO1.png

So far what I have in the models I made using AbstractBaseUser, I have only the normal user information and wanted to inherit from this User that I have these two other fields: The Teacher and licensing it with the specific fields I want. Here's my account model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Usuário deve ter um email")

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
    )
    user.staff = is_staff
    user.admin = is_admin
    user.active = is_active
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True
    )
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
    )
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Usuário')
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nome')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Sobrenome')
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    pass

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.staff

@property
def is_admin(self):
    return self.admin

@property
def is_active(self):
    return self.active

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Usuário'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'
```

Also, after inheriting Professor and User-based licensing, how would I render it in the template? Here's the log view so far:

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core:home'))
    template_name = 'contas/register.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('core:home')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: I would not inherit if I were you. I would extend by having 3 different profiles with a one-to-one relationship to the user: a `TeacherProfile`, a `LicensingProfile` and a `UserProfile`, each with their own fields. Your registration view would thus render 4 forms (and with javascript you can hide/unhide the correct profile form) and process 4 forms. The chosen one is saved, next to the `RegisterForm`. You could add a `type` field to your `User` model to make sure only one profile is used, if you're sure a user will never have two or three profiles at the same time.

Comment: Thank your for your help, dirkgroten. I was able to create both the Teacher and Graduating type, I created a form for each one and checked if they are valid or not in the view. In the template I used show and hide methods (jquery) to show which fields I want to appear when I click Teacher or Other. When I click to Teacher everything records perfectly, but when I click only on Other the form does not send, as if he was trying to validate the fields of "Teacher".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i didn't get it wrong you need different forms for registering 3 different user types. right?
for that you must define 3 different forms in forms.py and pass all that to your front-end then with javascript change which form is being shown and pass another extra paramter to your view e.g. (form_type=teacher)
and your view would be

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form_type is the form type data you're gonna send via form post
        # that which teacher or license or other was selected
        form_type = request.POST.get('form_type')

        if form_type == 'teacher':
             form = TeacherRegisterForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 ...
        elif form_type == 'license':
             form = LicenseRegisterForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 ...
        elif form_type == 'other':
             form = OtherRegisterForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 ...
```